# golang bufio in object

Tags: object, struct, go

I'm fairly new to Golang; previously used Python.

I am having difficult time to apply bufio in the object.

```
type fout struct {
    filename string
    fo File 
    bfo Writer

}
func (a *fout) init() {
    a.fo,_:=os.Open(a.filename)
    a.bfo:=bufio.NewWriter(fo)
}
```

Basically, I like to create objects; each will have it's filename, and bufio will be used.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Every use of a name from another package needs to be prefixed with the package name--so `fo File` has to be `fo *os.File`. You normally declare `*bufio.Writer` and `*os.File` as pointers (see the bufio and file docs at http://golang.org/pkg/) You want plain `=`, not `:=`, for assigning to attributes like `a.fo` and `a.bfo`. Don't throw away errors, particularly if you're used to exceptions, or you'll have impossible-to-debug problems. (For a trivial script for learning you can `if err != nil { panic(...) }`, but for real use, you almost always want to return them.)

Comment: @twotwotwo i'm new to stackoverflow; how can i choose your answer as "the answer"?

Comment: You couldn't because that wasn't an "answer", but I've posted one you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things in the code sample:

- Every use of a name from another package needs to be prefixed with the package name--so `fo File` has to be `fo *os.File`.
- You normally declare `*bufio.Writer` and `*os.File` as pointers (see the bufio and file docs at http://golang.org/pkg)
- You want plain `=`, not `:=`, for assigning to attributes like `a.fo` and `a.bfo`.
- Don't throw away errors, particularly if you're used to exceptions, or you'll have impossible-to-debug problems. (For a trivial script for learning you can `if err != nil { panic(err) }`, but for real use, you almost always want to return them.)

It could also help to review the [tour](http://tour.golang.org/), pick up some tricks/advice from the various [talks](http://talks.golang.org/) and [blog posts](http://blog.golang.org/), maybe walk through [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/) (I admit I haven't persionally used it but sounds like it could be useful when getting started), look at some open-source Go code (projects on Github, the stdlib, anything), and run through [the surprisingly readable spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) once you're at the level where you want to know how the language really works.